# How to get YouTube most popular videos but for all time or last 30 days?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using [the YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?chart=mostPopular
```

to get the most popular videos ([it can be tried on this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)). But it seems they are the most popular videos within the last 24 hours or 48 hours.  Is there a way to get the most popular videos, say, for the last week, last month, or all time?  It seems it is possible to get all time, as someone is doing [an automated list of all time most popular YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLirAqAtl_h2r5g8xGajEwdXd3x1sZh8hC). So I wonder if it can be done for last month or any variation at all. (I don't know how it defines the "most popular" as on that API page -- maybe it is last 24 hours.)